# Change image color dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a .png or .jpeg image.  I want to change the color of the image ( previously may be it was white I want to change it to red ) according to the theme selected.  How can I do this.

Comment: Why do you need an image for this (Can't you just use CSS)? Failing that, look at CSS filters, where you might be able to adjust the hue of the image, but I suspect this isn't what you want.

Comment: In that case you need to change the image itself based on theme

Comment: actually we are using material design in our website so on the same image we want different color on different scenario ( like hover, click, clicked etc. )

Comment: @SarojJena I'm added an answer below,don't forget to tick it if it,s useful

Answer (score 3):

you can do it by

- **add an `<div>` tag on top of the image**
- change it's opacity to .5 or lower
- change it's colour using js on click

I'm added an snippet below.

```js
document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundColor = "green";
});
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
document.getElementById("blue").addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
```

```css
img{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  z-index:900;
  }
#canvas{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  opacity:0.3;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  }
button{
  float:right;
  /*margin-top:200px;*/
  margin-right:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="canvas"></div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwy2w.jpg" id="image">

<button id="green">green</button>
<button id="red">red</button>
<button id="blue">blue</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
img#theImage {
        filter: hue-rotate(90deg);
}
```

You'll have to experiment with different deg values, and it'll vary from image to image, so not ideally what your after, but it's as close as you'll get with html/css/jquery.

Comment: what is the filter attribute actually do.

Comment: It applies a filter, there's a whole bunch of different filters, but this one in particular edits the hue. See for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Comment: Also hue shifting will **not** change the colour of an image that is already grayscale.